# How to implement a spell checker in random number generator in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, random, scripting, generator

Just finished scripting a number generator game that requires a user to guess a number between 1 and 100, I was curious if there is a way to make the script only accept numbers in between the 1-100 number range and reject any letter characters? I tried using

```
typeset -i
```

But i'm not sure if I am fully utilizing it or missing something, here is the rest of the code

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$((RANDOM%100))
typeset -i attempts=0
until [[ $guess == $num ]]
do
    echo -n "Enter your guessing number: "
    read -r guess
    if (( guess < num ));
    then echo "Guess Higher..."
    elif (( guess > num ));
    then echo "Guess Lower..."
    fi
(( attempts++ )) 
done
printf "Congradulations! it took $attempts guesses!\n"
```

Comment: does your code run? what happens if you enter a number outside the desired range (1..100)? what happens if you enter a non-integer (eg, a letter or word)?

Comment: Yeah the code runs as it is intended, If I enter a character or number outside of the range the script still accepts it and tells to "Guess Higher..." I just need it to reject character or numbers outside of the number range.

Comment: see [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118856/check-if-reply-is-in-a-range-of-numbers), [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151654/checking-if-an-input-number-is-an-integer)

Comment: I believe `typeset -i` just makes any subsequent assignment of a non-integer be treated as `0`

Comment: @jhnc : This would be true only for assigning a string strating with a non-digit. If I assign a mixed string starting with a digit, for instance `5Z`, I get the cryptic error message _value too great for base_ and the value of the variable would not change (i.e. not forced to be zero). Hence a "poor man's checker" would indeed be to `typeset -i guess`, set the variable explicitly to 0 before reading it, and then testing it whether it is in the numerically allowed range.

Answer (score 2):

> accept numbers in between the 1-100 number range and reject any letter characters?

So use some utility to check the input. You could use a regex to check if the input consist only of digits and after that check the range.

```
echo -n "Enter your guessing number: "
read -r guess
if ! [[ $guess=~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      echo "Your guess is not a number, try again..."
      continue;
fi
if (( guess < 1 )); then
     echo "Your guess is lower then 1, try again..."

fi
if (( guess > 100 )); then
     echo "Your guess is higher then 100, try again..."
     continue
fi
# rest of your script
```

You can use:

```
typeset -i guess
read -r guess
```

but that will convert any input into a number without error checking. If you input `blabla`, `guess` will just be `0`, with no error checking.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the test around and use a wildcard pattern (globbing) to check, whether the variable contains an illegal character:

```
if [[ $guess == *[^0-9]* ]]
then
  echo Value is not an natural number
elif ((guess == 0 || guess > 100))
  echo Value is out of range
else
  ... do your game here
fi
```